# jQuery: Button enable is not working

Tags: jquery

My jsfiddle is here- http://jsfiddle.net/hhimanshu/HVRLA/

**Need**
- As soon as text is entered the "create" button should enable
- if there is no text(text length = 0), "create" button should be disabled again

**UPDATE**

The proposed solution works for the solution, but it doesn't work with the I have the form in dropdown. Here is the fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/hhimanshu/ukYek/

Comment: Just a sidenote: `$(input)` is not necessary, you can do directly `input.keyup(...)`

Comment: And, the fiddle is wrong, there's no "new-list", but "new-playlist". As for the former thing, you have `var input=$("something");`, so `input` is *already* a JQuery object, and as such it can be used.

Comment: and that was the issue, thank you @Cranio

Comment: You should have posted the actual markup (with the dropdown) originally, then I could have given you an answer that works with your code and wouldn't have received an unnecessary down vote. Looks like someone doesn't know how to use that down vote button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you weren't selecting the button correctly, and you forgot to put an `else` to make it disable again if there are no characters in the input (i.e. the user backspaces all of the text that they entered). This works:

```
$(function(){
    var input = $('#new-list :input');
    $(input).keyup(function(){
      //alert($(input).val().length);                
        if ($(input).val().length > 0) {
            //alert($(input).val().length);
            $('#new-list button[type="submit"]').removeAttr('disabled');
        }
        else {
            $('#new-list button[type="submit"]').attr('disabled',true);
        }
    });
});
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HVRLA/2/

Comment: Thanks @Nathan, but this is not working in  http://jsfiddle.net/hhimanshu/ukYek/ fiddle, Ia m screwing somewhere it seems

Comment: Why the downvote? Just because my answer doesn't work with the other markup that was not originally posted, doesn't mean it needs a downvote. It works with the original markup and code in the jsfiddle, therefore it does **not** need a downvote.

Answer (score 0):

Another Solution : http://jsfiddle.net/HVRLA/5/

**EDIT:**

As in your comment below this http://jsfiddle.net/hhimanshu/ukYek/ fiddle was not working.
You had a problem in input selector:

```
$(function(){
    var input = $('#new-playlist :input');
    $(input).live('keyup',function(){
      //alert($(input).val().length);                
        if ($(input).val().length > 0) {
            //alert($(input).val().length);
            $('#create-playlist-button').removeAttr('disabled');
        }
        else {
            $('#create-playlist-button').attr('disabled',true);
        }
    });
});​
```

I think this was the problem in your code -as their is no `new-list` id in your html

```
 var input = $('#new-list :input');
```

So i just changed it to this :

```
var input = $('#new-playlist :input');
```

Here is the fiddle link : http://jsfiddle.net/ukYek/3/

Comment: Thanks @Mohammad, it doesn't seem to work  http://jsfiddle.net/hhimanshu/ukYek/, something I am missing

Answer (score 0):

A working example:

```
$(function(){
    var input = $('#new-playlist :input');
    input.live('keyup',function(){   
            $('#create-playlist-button').attr('disabled',input.val().length==0);
     });
});​
```

Comment: @daydreamer Check out this more compact form, maybe you'll like it :)

Comment: input.val() is undefined is what i see. Though I like the compact version

Comment: yeah, not in the fiddle though something I am not doing right